# Auto generate email account during Drupal account registration?

Tags: php, drupal, email

I was wondering how to auto generate a user email accounts in Drupal?  I do not have a host currently but am trying to get my head around how this would be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Postfix mail server [allows you to use a set of MySQL tables](http://www.postfix.org/MYSQL_README.html) to set up mail accounts. With a little bit of custom coding against `hook_user()`, you could have new users get added to your Postfix tables and thus have e-mail addresses all nicely setup ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Drupal module for that: the [Mailfix for Postfix](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailfix) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... integrates Drupal with Postfix, providing email accounts to regular Drupal accounts.
>
> For this module to work you must have previously installed and configured Postfix 2.1 or greater. A step-by-step installation guide for an Ubuntu 8.04 server is available at HowToForge.
>
> Once your Postfix server is appropriately configured you may install this Drupal module.

Answer (score 0):

The other way you could do it is by using `exec` on your local server to run a script which adds a mail account. It really depends on your server environment.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is not an email server - hence you must connect Drupal to an email server in some way, most likely through the use of a custom module.